# eigenspaces determining if diagonalisable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

[image]

I'm on (iii),

We defined Eigenspaces as follows; $$E_\lambda = \{ \underline{v} \in \mathbb{F^n} | A\underline{v} = \lambda \underline{v} \}$$

For the matrix I found the eigen values to be $0,0,2$ and solving $A\underline{v} = \lambda \underline{v}$ for $\lambda = 0$ I get 3 equations which all say the same thing:

$2x_1 + 3x_2 + x_3 = 0$, I don't really know what to do for this, but I gave it a go: 
$x_1 = -3/2 x_2 -1/2 x_3$, so $x_2,x_3$ are free to be anything, let them be $t_1,t_2$ respectively, then I stated that $E_0 =  \left \{ \underline{v} \in \mathbb{F^n} | \underline{v} = t_1 \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{3}{2} \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + t_2 \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}, t_1t_2 \in \mathbb{R} \right \}$ and concluding with the dimension being 2.

Is the above correct?

My second question is how can we determine from this if the matrix is diagonalisable? What am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: It is diagonalizable. It has eigenvalues of 0,  0, and 2 so these are the entries along its diagonal in the proper (eigen) basis.

Comment: You seem to be good regarding the eigenspace. It is customary to express the vectors in terms of integer entries (absorbing fractions into the scalars), but the space is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A matrix is diagonalizable if, and only if, there is a basis of $\mathbb F^n$ in which all the elements are eigenvectors of the matrix at hand.

On the whole exercise you have $\mathbb F=\mathbb R$ and $n=3$.

Thus, each matrix will be diagonalizable if, and only if, you can find three linearly indepedent eigenvectors.

In $(iii)$ you have already found two linearly independent eigenvectors, (yes, what you did is correct). Since $n=3$, it is possible to guarantee that the matrix is diagonalizable because if you go find an eigenvector for the eigenvalue $2$ it will necessarily be linearly indepedent from $E_0$ because of this fact: eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are necessarily linearly independent.

A nitpick: $E_0$, as you wrote it, it's senseless you should choose one of this ways of writing it:

$$E_0 =  \left \{ \underline{v} \in \mathbb{R^n} \mid \exists  t_1t_2 \in \mathbb{R} \left(\underline{v} = t_1 \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{3}{2} \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + t_2 \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\right)\right \},$$
$$E_0 =  \left \{ t_1\begin{pmatrix} -\frac{3}{2} \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + t_2 \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \mid  t_1t_2 \in \mathbb{R} \right \},$$
$$\left\langle \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{3}{2} \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}\right\rangle\color{grey}{=\left\langle \begin{pmatrix} -3 \\ 2 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}\right\rangle}.$$

Answer (score 1):

An n×n matrix A over the field F is diagonalizable if and only if the sum of the dimensions of its eigenspaces is equal to n, which is the case if and only if there exists a basis of F^n consisting of eigenvectors of A. F here is the set of real numbers.

You have one eigenspace of dimension two and another of dimension one (check this fact for yourself). 2+1=3=n. So, your matrix is diagonalizable. The entries along the diagonal are the eigenvalues, in the order of your eigenbasis.